# Placing a collection of values into a For...each loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, collections

I have this code written to return a collection of an object with properties as follows:

```
Public Shared Function Create() As Collection(Of Element)
    Return New Collection(Of Element)() From { _
     New Element() With { _
      .Group = 1, _
      .Period = 1, _
      .Name = "Hydrogen" _
     }, _
     New Element() With { _
      .Group = 18, _
      .Period = 1, _
      .Name = "Helium" _
     }, _
     New Element() With { _
      .Group = 1, _
      .Period = 2, _
      .Name = "Lithium" _
     }
    }
End Function
```

I would now like to get these values from a database, but I can't figure out how to reformat the code. My returning procedure should be something like this:

```
    Public Shared Function CreateDB() As Collection(Of Element)

        Using db As New DataClassesDataContext(ACCCon)

            Dim rows = (From row In db.PeriodicTableQs
                       Order By row.ID
                       Select row).ToList()
            For Each s In rows
              <<collect the elements here as result>>
              <<eg, New Element() With {.Group = s.Group}>>
            Next

        End Using

        Return Result

    End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not return the `row`, which is a `List(Of  PeriodicTableQs)`, instead of casting it manually to a different type?

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of avoiding to rewrite a lot of code that is using that class... That solves it; but would still be really glad to know how to rewrite the loop, I have other places I know I will definitely need to replace arrays with database calls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Shared Function CreateDB() As Collection(Of Element)
  Dim ACCCon As String = "ConnectionString"

  Using db As New DataClassesDataContext(ACCCon)
    Dim List = db.PeriodicTableQs.
      OrderBy(Function(Q) Q.ID).ToList.
      Select(Function(row)                          
               Return New Element With {                          
                 .Group = row.Group,                          
                 .Name = row.Name,                          
                 .Period = row.Period                          
               }                          
             End Function)
  End Using

  Return New Collection(Of Element)(List)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, InteXX. Seems what I was looking for, but I am getting this error: 'Statement Lambdas cannot be converted to Expression trees' at the start of 'Function(row)'. I have added the call to the database returning the row above the 'Dim List ...' part

Comment: @HanningtonMambo put `ToList` before `Select`

Comment: @HanningtonMambo: Fabio is correct—I tested my sample with a mockup `DataClassesDataContext` class, not a real `DataContext`. I've edited my answer accordingly.